# add json attribute with the URL of any object included in the response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, routes, dry

I am working in an API (without using any gem), and I would like to have nice responses.

That is,

- If the Api consumer ask for a list of objects: the API will respond with a list of objects showing only a couple of fields and **adding a field with the url** that will access to all the fields of this specific object
- If the API consumer ask for an specific object it will respond with all the fields.

To do that, I've a controller like this:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class QuotesController < ApplicationController

      respond_to :json

      def index
        @quotes = Quote.all
        respond_with @quotes
      end

      def show
        @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
        respond_with @quote
      end

    end
  end
end
```

This is the model:

```
   class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessible :author, :text
   end
```

**How can I add the URL or PATH of any Quote** in the Quote.all response?

**Would it be possible to include this URL** in any json response that includes that object? I mean, being DRY

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you'll have to customize your JSON response.

I would recommend you replace the `respond_with` with some jbuilder templates with something like this:

```
# app/views/quotes/index.json.jbuilder
json.quotes @quotes do |quote|
  json.id quote.id
  json.name quote.name
  json.amount quote.amount
  json.url quote_url(quote)
end

# app/views/quotes/show.json.jbuilder
json.quote do
  json.id @quote.id
  json.name @quote.name
  json.amount @quote.amount
  json.url quote_url(@quote)
end
```